# React Native Failed to load bundle

Tags: react-native, bundle

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I have already tried `"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0"`
and `npm install` and clean cache and deleting node modules.

Comment: Where are you getting the error - phone, emulator?

Comment: emulator @ShellNinja

Comment: are you sure that your packager is running correctly on port 8081? or doyou change the native ios source that defines bundle address?

Comment: in my packager.env 
'export RCT_METRO_PORT=8081' 
@AliSn

Comment: Maybe the port is not properly released and node is not complaining. Did you try killing all node processes and restarting packager? Or simply restart the computer?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue as you. I tried this:

1. Close Metro Bundle
2. Back to terminal
3. `npm start` your app directory
4. Go to simulator and press Cmd + R

It works for me, I hope it helps you.